# deep copy without using serialize/deserialize

Tags: c#, deep-copy

How deep copy a class object without doing serialize/deserialize?

For example

```
public class Book
{
    public string Chapter { get; set;}
    public int Page { get; set;}
}

public void Main ()
{
   Book newBook = new Book();
   newBook.Chapter = "Physical";
   newBook.Page = 40;

   Book oldBook = newBook; 
   
   newBook.Chapter = "Chemical";
   newBook.Page = 60;
   
}

------------------------------
output
newBook.Chapter: Chemical
newBook.Page: 60

oldBook.Chapter: Chemical
oldBook.Page: 60
```

but i want this

newBook.Chapter: Chemical 
newBook.Page: 60

oldBook.Chapter: Physical 
oldBook.Page: 40

Comment: Hi @Nan - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects this may be of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization and deserialization are popular when the object has enough properties that writing custom code would be time-consuming, but you can just write:

```
public static class BookExtensions
{
    public static Book Clone(this Book source)
    {
        return new Book {Chapter = source.Chapter, Page = source.Page};
    }
}
```

or make it a method of `Book`. Whether to do this or create an extension (above) is a matter of preference. If the method is in `Book` then you're more likely to remember to update the method if the class changes.

```cs
public class Book
{
    public string Chapter { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }

    public Book Clone()
    {
        return new Book {Chapter = Chapter, Page = Page};
    }
}
```

(There's an [`ICloneable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable) interface you can implement, but it's not popular. The `Clone` method returns `object` and you have to cast it.)

Another approach is to use a `struct` or `record`. You're likely cloning so that you can have an instance identical to another instance, but you can modify its properties without changing the first instance.

If you change your `Book` class to a `struct`, this test passes:

```cs
var book = new Book {Chapter = "x", Page = 1};
var book2 = book;
book2.Page = 2;
Assert.AreEqual(1, book.Page);
```

No need to clone anything.

Or you could create a `record`:

```cs
public record class Book(string chapter, int page)
{ }
```

and this test passes:

```cs
var book = new Book("x", 1);
var book2 = book with {page = 2};
Assert.AreEqual(1, book.page);
```

Each `Book` is immutable. You can pass it around to various methods and whenever a property needs to "change", a statement like `var book2 = book with {page = 2};` creates a new book and only updates the specified property. No need to clone.

Comment: But this is no deep clone.

Comment: The first part is a deep clone. The second part is about why a deep clone is necessary, and questioning whether we can eliminate the need for it.

Answer (score -1):

It is also possible to create deep copy of the object with AutoMapper library. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74089319/6158341