# Deep-copy with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, .net-6.0, deep-copy

I want to create a deep copy of an object. I chose to use the automapper because this way I dont have to edit classes and add there any extra code. Plus I use automapper for mapping my classes to DTOs.

On my surprise when I wanted to do a copy like:

```
var original = new TrainingSetDto()
var output = _mapper.Map<TrainingSetDto>(original);
```

the `output` variable retrieved reference to the `original` variable (shallow copy).

How to achieve my wanted result (deep copy of the `original`) to get new instance with same properties ?

E.g. on this blog
https://jshowers.com/create-deep-copies-of-object-in-c-using-automapper/
was mentioned that static call `Mapper.Map<Person>(originalPerson);` is the way how to do so. But these static methods are not there anymore.

Could you please point me to the right direction ?

Comment: You need to explicitly create maps for all the classes you want copied, otherwise they'll just be assigned.

Comment: I have tried to add `CreateMap<TrainingSetDto, TrainingSetDto>();` into my AutoMapper config but even then I received just the copy by reference.

Comment: That's just wrong. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu It works as you said but just in Console app. In API project it doesnt. Repro here: https://github.com/Kebechet/AutoMapperProblem Project: `ApiTest` ...just trigger the Get endpoint through swagger to trigger the functionality

Comment: Seems like a bug in AutoMapper dependency injection package. See my discussion: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/4107#discussioncomment-3890041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LucianBargoanu pointed out it is possible to do a deep copy by `AutoMapper`.
By firstly specifying map for your object e.g.

```
CreateMap<TrainingSetDto, TrainingSetDto>();
```

and then just calling your mapping function

```
var copy = _mapper.Map<TrainingSetDto>(original);
```

I was able to reproduce the correct behavior in the [Console app](https://github.com/Kebechet/AutoMapperProblem/tree/main/AutoMapperProblem) but in the [API project](https://github.com/Kebechet/AutoMapperProblem/tree/main/ApiTest) it still didnt work correctly.

Finally the problem in the API project was in the dependency injection package: `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`. And thats why when I replaced:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(provider => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
    cfg.AddMaps(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(x => x.FullName));
}));
```

by:

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
    cfg.AddMaps(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(x => x.FullName));
}).CreateMapper());
```

it started to work correcly.

PS: I put my findings also to the [discussion thread](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/4107#discussioncomment-3890041) on AutoMapper github, but for some reason they deleted my comment and locked the thread.

Comment: Since I was already using automapper within the exsiting project, this solution was the most appropriate to achieve deepcopy, over other deep copy methods.